# Statistical test for association between multiple variables

Tags: statistical-significance

I am trying to study association between blood groups (categorical variable) and cholesterol levels (continuous variable) adjusted for confounders?
I was wondering which statistical test would be more appropriate? Thank you beforehand for any assistance.

Comment: Have you thought about ANOVA?

Comment: Example: http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~martin/W2024/R3.pdf

Comment: If i know correctly, ANOVA is same as linear regression. But would it be better to use GLM then? Thank you

Comment: The purpose of using a GLM such as logistic or log-linear models would be to account for different data types and assumptions. Why would using a GLM be more suitable than ANOVA for your situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my comment, given the context of your data, 1 categorical variable and 1 continuous variable, an appropriate analysis would involve something like ANOVA.

If you are unfamiliar with ANOVA, I recommend reviewing Chapter 16 ANOVA from *Practical Regression and Anova using R* by Faraway. If you have other confounding variables, Two-way ANOVA may be an appropriate model.

https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Faraway-PRA.pdf

Comment: thank you would it be still applicable if there are continuous and categorical independent variables?

Comment: Yes. With ANOVA or linear regression, your dependent variable is continuous and your independent variable(s) can be continuous or categorical.